# change value in specific rows with column conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` with two columns `gender, score`.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      gender         |     score        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          male       |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          female     |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          male       |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          female     |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          male       |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to change scores of males (`gender == 'male'`) from row 3 to row 5 to be 0, expected output:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      gender         |     score        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          male       |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          female     |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          male       |         0        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          female     |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          male       |         0        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

How can I combine `iloc` with that condition?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please include an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: You should use loc not iloc here. `df.loc[df.gender == 'male', 'score'] = 0`

Comment: @AntonvBR I don't want to change the first row while the gender is male.

Comment: @Harold My bad.

Comment: Is "3 to 5" a hardwired condition? Or do you believe that you have a case of replicated data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Alt1:

You could do it with two masks (conditions). This should be readable and make sense.

```
m1 = (df.gender == 'male')
m2 = (df.gender.duplicated())

df.loc[m1&m2, 'score'] = 0
```

#### Alt2:

Slice away the first truth value of the nonzero mask (requires `import numpy as np`). This should be faster.

```
m = np.nonzero(df.gender=='male')[0][1:]
df.loc[m, 'score'] = 0
```

---

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'gender': ['male','female','male','female','male'],
    'score': 34
})

m1 = (df.gender == 'male')
m2 = (df.gender.duplicated())

m = np.nonzero(df.gender=='male')[0][1:]
df.loc[m, 'score'] = 0

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   gender  score
0    male     34
1  female     34
2    male      0
3  female     34
4    male      0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need,

```
m=df.loc[2:5,:].loc[df['gender']=='male']
df.loc[m.index,'score']=0
print(df)
    gender  score
0   male    34
1   female  34
2   male    0
3   female  34
4   male    0
```